# How to MySQL REPLACE html/mjml code with html tags

Tags: html, mysql, find-replace, mjml

I have a lot of email templates stored in MySQL database.
Inside i have a table which stores the MJML code of the template.
Now I want to update a few lines of code in all of my emails. And I want to do it inside MySQL because it would be fast. (hundreds of emails)

The table "mymjmltemplates" has three columns:

```
id int(10), email_id int(10), custom_mjml (longtext)
```

My query goes like this:

```
UPDATE mymjmltemplates 
SET custom_mjml = REPLACE(
        custom_mjml,
        '<mj-column>
            <mj-text>Content 1
            </mj-text>
        </mj-column>',
        '<mj-column>
            <mj-text>Content 2
            </mj-text>
        </mj-column>') 
WHERE email_id = 1035;
```

Usually this query updates strings. But when I run it, it breaks somewhere and asks during the query:

```
Display all 2709 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Without entering something it finishes the query, and changes nothing.

So, it is escaping somehow inside the strings??? I don't find a connection.

This is how it looks like on my cli:

```
    MariaDB [mydatabase]> UPDATE mymjmltemplates 
    -> SET custom_mjml = REPLACE(custom_mjml,
    -> 
Display all 2709 possibilities? (y or n)
    -> >
    -> 
Display all 2709 possibilities? (y or n)
    -> tent 1
    -> 
Display all 2709 possibilities? (y or n)
?                                                     categories.description                                leads.state
ABS                                                   categories.id                                         leads.storecode
ACOS                                                  categories.is_published                               leads.timezone
ACTION                                                categories.modified_by                                leads.title
ADD                                                   categories.modified_by_user                           leads.treueaktion_gutschein_ein
ADDDATE                                               categories.title                                      leads.twitter
ADDTIME                                               category_id                                           leads.warenkorbwert_abbruch
AES_DECRYPT                                           channel                                               leads.website
AES_ENCRYPT                                           channel_id                                            leads.weitere_informationen
AFTER                                                 channel_url_trackables                                leads.zahlungsart
AGAINST                                               channel_url_trackables.channel                        leads.zipcode
AGGREGATE                                             channel_url_trackables.channel_id                     line_count
ALGORITHM                                             channel_url_trackables.hits                           linkedin
ALL                                                   channel_url_trackables.redirect_id                    list_id
ALTER                                                 channel_url_trackables.unique_hits                    lists
ANALYZE                                               charset                                               load data from
AND                                                   checked_out                                           locale
ANY                                                   checked_out_by                                        lock tables
AREA                                                  checked_out_by_user                                   log_counts_processed
AS                                                    city                                                  log_id
ASBINARY                                              clear                                                 manually_added
ASC                                                   click_count                                           manually_removed
ASCII                                                 click_details                                         markenbotschafter
ASENSITIVE                                            client_id                                             mautic
ASIN                                                  client_info                                           max_attempts
ASTEXT                                                code                                                  media_id
ASWKB                                                 color                                                 media_path
ASWKT                                                 column_is_not_created                                 merged_id
ATAN                                                  column_name                                           message
ATAN2                                                 column_type                                           message_channels
AUTO_INCREMENT                                        column_value                                          message_channels.channel
AVG                                                   columns                                               message_channels.channel_id
AVG_ROW_LENGTH                                        comments                                              message_channels.id
BACKUP                                                companies                                             message_channels.is_enabled
BDB                                                   companies.checked_out                                 message_channels.message_id
BEFORE                                                companies.checked_out_by                              message_channels.properties
BEGIN                                                 companies.checked_out_by_user                         message_id
BENCHMARK                                             companies.companyaddress1                             message_queue
BERKELEYDB                                            companies.companyaddress2                             message_queue.attempts
BETWEEN                                               companies.companyannual_revenue                       message_queue.channel
BIGINT                                                companies.companycity                                 message_queue.channel_id
BIN                                                   companies.companycountry                              message_queue.date_published
BINARY                                                companies.companydescription                          message_queue.date_sent
BINLOG                                                companies.companyemail                                message_queue.event_id
BIT                                                   companies.companyfax                                  message_queue.id
BIT_AND                                               companies.companyindustry                             message_queue.last_attempt
BIT_COUNT                                             companies.companyname                                 message_queue.lead_id
BIT_LENGTH                                            companies.companynumber_of_employees                  message_queue.max_attempts
BIT_OR                                                companies.companyphone                                message_queue.options
BIT_XOR                                               companies.companystate                                message_queue.priority
BLOB                                                  companies.companywebsite                              message_queue.scheduled_date
BOOL                                                  companies.companyzipcode                              message_queue.status
BOOLEAN                                               companies.created_by                                  message_queue.success
BOTH                                                  companies.created_by_user                             messages
BTREE                                                 companies.date_added                                  messages.category_id
BY                                                    companies.date_modified                               messages.checked_out
BYTE                                                  companies.id                                          messages.checked_out_by
CACHE                                                 companies.is_published                                messages.checked_out_by_user
CALL                                                  companies.modified_by                                 messages.created_by
CASCADE                                               companies.modified_by_user                            messages.created_by_user
CASCADED                                              companies.owner_id                                    messages.date_added
CASE                                                  companies.score                                       messages.date_modified
CAST                                                  companies.social_cache                                messages.description
CEIL                                                  companies_leads                                       messages.id
CEILING                                               companies_leads.company_id                            messages.is_published
CENTROID                                              companies_leads.date_added                            messages.modified_by
CHAIN                                                 companies_leads.is_primary                            messages.modified_by_user
CHANGE                                                companies_leads.lead_id                               messages.name
CHANGED                                               company                                               messages.publish_down
CHAR                                                  company_id                                            messages.publish_up
CHARACTER                                             companyaddress1                                       meta_description
CHARACTER_LENGTH                                      companyaddress2                                       metadata
CHARSET                                               companyannual_revenue                                 migrations
CHAR_LENGTH                                           companycity                                           migrations.executed_at
CHECK                                                 companycountry                                        migrations.version
CHECKSUM                                              companydescription                                    mime
CIPHER                                                companyemail                                          mobile
CLIENT                                                companyfax                                            mobileSettings
CLOSE                                                 companyindustry                                       modified_at
COALESCE                                              companyname                                           modified_by
CODE                                                  companynumber_of_employees                            modified_by_user
COERCIBILITY                                          companyphone                                          monitor_id
COLLATE                                               companystate                                          monitor_post_count
COLLATION                                             companywebsite                                        monitor_post_count.id
COLUMN                                                companyzipcode                                        monitor_post_count.monitor_id
COLUMNS                                               conditions                                            monitor_post_count.post_count
COMMENT                                               connect                                               monitor_post_count.post_date
COMMIT                                                contact_id                                            monitoring
COMMITTED                                             contact_merge_records                                 monitoring.category_id
COMPACT                                               contact_merge_records.contact_id                      monitoring.checked_out
COMPRESS                                              contact_merge_records.date_added                      monitoring.checked_out_by
COMPRESSED                                            contact_merge_records.id                              monitoring.checked_out_by_user
CONCAT                                                contact_merge_records.merged_id                       monitoring.created_by
CONCAT_WS                                             contact_merge_records.name                            monitoring.created_by_user
CONCURRENT                                            container_attr                                        monitoring.date_added
CONDITION                                             content                                               monitoring.date_modified
CONNECTION                                            copy_id                                               monitoring.description
CONNECTION_ID                                         country                                               monitoring.id
    -> >',
    '> 
Display all 2709 possibilities? (y or n)
    '> >
    '> 
Display all 2709 possibilities? (y or n)
    '> tent 2
    '> 
Display all 2709 possibilities? (y or n)
?                                                     categories.description                                leads.state
ABS                                                   categories.id                                         leads.storecode
ACOS                                                  categories.is_published                               leads.timezone
ACTION                                                categories.modified_by                                leads.title
ADD                                                   categories.modified_by_user                           leads.treueaktion_gutschein_ein
ADDDATE                                               categories.title                                      leads.twitter
ADDTIME                                               category_id                                           leads.warenkorbwert_abbruch
AES_DECRYPT                                           channel                                               leads.website
AES_ENCRYPT                                           channel_id                                            leads.weitere_informationen
AFTER                                                 channel_url_trackables                                leads.zahlungsart
AGAINST                                               channel_url_trackables.channel                        leads.zipcode
AGGREGATE                                             channel_url_trackables.channel_id                     line_count
ALGORITHM                                             channel_url_trackables.hits                           linkedin
ALL                                                   channel_url_trackables.redirect_id                    list_id
ALTER                                                 channel_url_trackables.unique_hits                    lists
ANALYZE                                               charset                                               load data from
AND                                                   checked_out                                           locale
ANY                                                   checked_out_by                                        lock tables
AREA                                                  checked_out_by_user                                   log_counts_processed
AS                                                    city                                                  log_id
ASBINARY                                              clear                                                 manually_added
ASC                                                   click_count                                           manually_removed
ASCII                                                 click_details                                         markenbotschafter
ASENSITIVE                                            client_id                                             mautic
ASIN                                                  client_info                                           max_attempts
ASTEXT                                                code                                                  media_id
ASWKB                                                 color                                                 media_path
ASWKT                                                 column_is_not_created                                 merged_id
ATAN                                                  column_name                                           message
ATAN2                                                 column_type                                           message_channels
AUTO_INCREMENT                                        column_value                                          message_channels.channel
AVG                                                   columns                                               message_channels.channel_id
AVG_ROW_LENGTH                                        comments                                              message_channels.id
BACKUP                                                companies                                             message_channels.is_enabled
BDB                                                   companies.checked_out                                 message_channels.message_id
BEFORE                                                companies.checked_out_by                              message_channels.properties
BEGIN                                                 companies.checked_out_by_user                         message_id
BENCHMARK                                             companies.companyaddress1                             message_queue
BERKELEYDB                                            companies.companyaddress2                             message_queue.attempts
BETWEEN                                               companies.companyannual_revenue                       message_queue.channel
BIGINT                                                companies.companycity                                 message_queue.channel_id
BIN                                                   companies.companycountry                              message_queue.date_published
BINARY                                                companies.companydescription                          message_queue.date_sent
BINLOG                                                companies.companyemail                                message_queue.event_id
BIT                                                   companies.companyfax                                  message_queue.id
BIT_AND                                               companies.companyindustry                             message_queue.last_attempt
BIT_COUNT                                             companies.companyname                                 message_queue.lead_id
BIT_LENGTH                                            companies.companynumber_of_employees                  message_queue.max_attempts
BIT_OR                                                companies.companyphone                                message_queue.options
BIT_XOR                                               companies.companystate                                message_queue.priority
BLOB                                                  companies.companywebsite                              message_queue.scheduled_date
BOOL                                                  companies.companyzipcode                              message_queue.status
BOOLEAN                                               companies.created_by                                  message_queue.success
BOTH                                                  companies.created_by_user                             messages
BTREE                                                 companies.date_added                                  messages.category_id
BY                                                    companies.date_modified                               messages.checked_out
BYTE                                                  companies.id                                          messages.checked_out_by
CACHE                                                 companies.is_published                                messages.checked_out_by_user
CALL                                                  companies.modified_by                                 messages.created_by
CASCADE                                               companies.modified_by_user                            messages.created_by_user
CASCADED                                              companies.owner_id                                    messages.date_added
CASE                                                  companies.score                                       messages.date_modified
CAST                                                  companies.social_cache                                messages.description
CEIL                                                  companies_leads                                       messages.id
CEILING                                               companies_leads.company_id                            messages.is_published
CENTROID                                              companies_leads.date_added                            messages.modified_by
CHAIN                                                 companies_leads.is_primary                            messages.modified_by_user
CHANGE                                                companies_leads.lead_id                               messages.name
CHANGED                                               company                                               messages.publish_down
CHAR                                                  company_id                                            messages.publish_up
CHARACTER                                             companyaddress1                                       meta_description
CHARACTER_LENGTH                                      companyaddress2                                       metadata
CHARSET                                               companyannual_revenue                                 migrations
CHAR_LENGTH                                           companycity                                           migrations.executed_at
CHECK                                                 companycountry                                        migrations.version
CHECKSUM                                              companydescription                                    mime
CIPHER                                                companyemail                                          mobile
CLIENT                                                companyfax                                            mobileSettings
CLOSE                                                 companyindustry                                       modified_at
COALESCE                                              companyname                                           modified_by
CODE                                                  companynumber_of_employees                            modified_by_user
COERCIBILITY                                          companyphone                                          monitor_id
COLLATE                                               companystate                                          monitor_post_count
COLLATION                                             companywebsite                                        monitor_post_count.id
COLUMN                                                companyzipcode                                        monitor_post_count.monitor_id
COLUMNS                                               conditions                                            monitor_post_count.post_count
COMMENT                                               connect                                               monitor_post_count.post_date
COMMIT                                                contact_id                                            monitoring
COMMITTED                                             contact_merge_records                                 monitoring.category_id
COMPACT                                               contact_merge_records.contact_id                      monitoring.checked_out
COMPRESS                                              contact_merge_records.date_added                      monitoring.checked_out_by
COMPRESSED                                            contact_merge_records.id                              monitoring.checked_out_by_user
CONCAT                                                contact_merge_records.merged_id                       monitoring.created_by
CONCAT_WS                                             contact_merge_records.name                            monitoring.created_by_user
CONCURRENT                                            container_attr                                        monitoring.date_added
CONDITION                                             content                                               monitoring.date_modified
CONNECTION                                            copy_id                                               monitoring.description
CONNECTION_ID                                         country                                               monitoring.id
    '> >') 
    -> WHERE email_id = 1035;
```

To me, it looks like some combinations of characters lead to escaping and then some weird things happen.
What am I doing wrong? Why is this happening?
I appreciate every help/idea

Comment: *My query goes like this* It is completely incorrect. You must use `'\\n'` or `'\\r\\n'` instead of multiline text literals.

Comment: ok. But how? if I do this instead:
`<mj-column>\\n<mj-text>Content 1\\n</mj-text>\\n</mj-column>`
it doesn't work as well. Could you give me an example?